# RecyclerView Width is Null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, width

I have a child recyclerView (childRecyclerView) and a TextView (labelTextView) above it that I use as a column label. I would like the width of the TextView to always match the width of the child recyclerView which is set to wrap_content.

I know I need to wait until the views are fully drawn. I have tried a bunch of things, but still get null for the child recyclerView width.

Please let me know if this code should be in onCreate(), inside the GET method, or other.

Kotlin preferred, but Java OK

I was expecting something like "labelTextView?.width = childRecyclerView?.width" placed inside my GET method to work.

Comment: Posting some code as well as the layout code would be helpful.